# C# RabbitMQ - EventingBasicConsumer.Received OutOfMemory

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I want a scenario with many consumers who listen to new messages and process them. The consumers should always be listening and process the messages when they are not null. This is the code I wrote:

```
        string msg = null;

        try
        {
            using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {

                queueMessage = queue.getQueue("myQueue");
                channel.BasicQos(prefetchSize: 0, prefetchCount: 1, global: false);
                consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                channel.BasicConsume(queue: "myQueue", noAck: false, consumer: consumer);

                while (true)
                {


                    consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
                    {
                        var body = ea.Body;
                        msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                        if (msg != null)
                        {
                            executeTask(msg);
                        }
                        channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag: ea.DeliveryTag, multiple: false);

                    };
                    channel.Dispose();
                    connection.Dispose();
                    consumer.Model.Dispose();
                }//while(true)
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { 
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

After a while, an OutOfMemoryException is thrown, most likely because there isn't a "flush" mechanism and the Received property becomes full. A rough solution could be to instantiate connection, channel and consumer inside the while(true):

```
        while (true)
        {
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {

                queueMessage = queue.getQueue("myQueue");
                channel.BasicQos(prefetchSize: 0, prefetchCount: 1, global: false);
                consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                channel.BasicConsume(queue: "myQueue", noAck: false, consumer: consumer);
                consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
                {
                ...
```

I am not at all convinced this is a good solution, because multiple thread are continuously opened and closed. May be a different class to handle this kind of behavior or am I missing something?

Comment: Is there any reason you are disposing the channel and connection inside the while loop?

Comment: Why are you subscribing to  consumer.Received event in while loop?

Comment: I dispose  channel and connection just for releasing unmanaged resource, but it's not necessary. I'm subscribing to consumer.Received event in while loop because otherwise my code would end once the message has been received and processed. I want my consumer to be always listening to new messages.

Answer (score 0):

First, the whole factory connection and client should be created in an object to which you will always have a reference while your service/program's lifecycle continues so that they don't get GC'd. Especially don't put them inside a using([]). Want multiple clients? -> separate threads and instances
Second, you do not need to use the 'while' and channel re-creation, because once you register some work to the consumer.Received and afterwards init the channel.BasicConsume, the work call will be kept in memory and called on each inbound message to the consumer